# IDLE partial execution

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, execution, python-idle

I only used Notebooks so far, and I have this question:

When running a python code with IDLE, do I have to execute the entirety of the Python script?

Or can I execute only a certain part, for example the 5 last lines?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

When you run a file from an IDLE editor, it hands the whole file to python to compile and execute, the same as if you entered `python -i filename` in the system terminal or console.